# Phone gets really hot in certain spot when charging?

Tags: battery, iphone, charging

[image: Cracked Phone]My iPhone 4s keeps getting really really hot in the top right corner when i start charging it. Its mainly along the top, near the turn off button, all down the right side, and near the camera on the back. This causes my phone to charge really slowly and causes it to turn off multiple times due to overheating. Is this dangerous?

Comment: **update** my phone is really heating up lots, i think i may have burnt my fingers. Also, the camera has small green and pink lines at the bottom, and everything is turning a tinted green. Is this due to the overheating???

Comment: Do you have pictures of what you're describing?

Comment: @fabriced i have just added a picture of the cracked screen; unfortunately i do not have a picture of my camera with the stripes

Comment: IMO, it's time for a new (used) iPhone. I'd list this one on eBay for literally about $20, under "For Parts or Repair". On eBay one can get a used iPhone 5 for less than $200, a used iPhone 5S for around $300-$350, and a used iPhone 6 for $450+. You also might consider getting a new iPhone 6S, it launches today.